# Number of subsequence with k distinct characters

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, strings, substrings, subsequences

"*A string is a subsequence of a given string, that is generated by deleting some(possibly zero) character of a given string without changing its order.*"

Suppose we have string s="***aabca***" and k=***3***. ( I will refer the three ***a***s as a1,a2 and a3 just to distinguish them).
So number of subsequence with 3 distinct characters are -

**7** => *(a1)bc*, *(a2)bc*, *bc(a3)*, *(a1)(a2)bc*, *(a1)bc(a3)*, *(a2)bc(a3)*, *(a1)(a2)bc(a3)*

I know how to calculate the answer for number of [substring with k distinct character](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-substrings-with-exactly-k-distinct-characters/). How to do it for subsequence?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $c$ types of balls, and there are $n_i$ balls of type $i$. Let $S$ be a set of types of balls. In how many ways can we choose balls so that only balls of type $S$ appear, and at least one ball of type $i$ appears for each $i \in S$? The answer is clearly
$$ \prod_{i \in S} (2^{n_i} - 1). $$
Taking $S = \{1,\ldots,c\}$, we get a solution to your problem in the case where $k$ is the number of different characters in the original string (in your example, $n_1 = 3$ and $n_2=n_3=1$).

You are interested in the value of the above when summed over all sets $S$ of size $k$. This is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the generating function
$$
\prod_{i=1}^c (1 + (2^{n_i}-1)x).
$$
This coefficient can be computed using dynamic programming. Details left to you.